# OS X retina MouseEvent coordination

Tags: java, macos, swing, jogl, hidpi

I am creating Java Swing Application using JOGL.

I want to get mouse coordination when mouse clicked in `GLJPanel`.
If I experiment with a Retina display, a return coordinate is strange.
The more deviation the coordinates are from the origin, the larger the gap.
(I test only two model of Mac Book Pro for Retina)
In my exam, that phenomenon does not occur except for Mac Book Pro Retina.

I want to unproject the event local coordination to global one,
so I ask in JOGL community, but I was advised it cause from HiDPI.

I want to know the standard way to get local coordination of MouseEvent
in HiDPI - Retina Display models of Macintosh first,
and in the near future for Windows HiDPI models.

Comment: Question already answered here: http://forum.jogamp.org/How-to-refer-GL-context-in-AWT-Mouse-Event-tp4037905p4038016.html JOGL specific questions should be asked only on our official forum.